# How to make MapStruct select alternate source fields to map to a single target field based on a flag in the source class

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
// the Source and Target classes:

public class Source {                   public class Target {    
    public A a;  ----------------\
                    XOR           > ------> AorB a_or_b;
    public B b;  ----------------/
                                        }
    public boolean flag;
}


// The Mapper
interface Mapper {
    @Mapping(target = "a_or_b", source = "source.a", conditionExpression = "java(source.flag == true)")
    // MapStruct complain on the following line with a java: Target property "a_or_b" must not be mapped more than once.
    @Mapping(target = "a_or_b", source = "source.b", conditionExpression = "java(source.flag == false)")
    Target map(Source source);

    AorB map(A a); // this mapper func should be invoqued by MapStruct when source.flag == true
    AorB map(B b); // this mapper func should be invoqued by MapStruct when source.flag == false
}
```

I'd like to be able to map either `Source.a` *XOR* `Source.b` into `target.a_or_b`.
Knowing that I have the mapper functions ready to `map from A to AorB` and to `map from B to AorB`, my problem is to make MapStruct choose the right source field depending upon the `source.flag` value.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

After having tried several techniques for a while and reading answers to nearby questions, I found a working solution. I answer my own question so that it might help others who are strugling with the same problem (Greg. L. DTSI/SI, I'm thinking about you).

The solution is to provide MapStruct with a hand written function that test for the desired condition and route to another mapping methods.
You must inform MapStruct to call your handwritten routing function by using `qualifiedByName="<name>"` and `@Named("<name>")`.

The control flow starts from a *MapStruct-generated function* `--to-->` *your handwritten routing function* `--and back-->` *to one of the MapStruct-generated functions* selected by your routing function.

Example Mapper code:

```java
interface Mapper {
    @Mapping(target = "a_or_b", source = ".", qualifiedByName="map_a_or_b")
    Target map(Source source);

    @Named("map_a_or_b")
    default AorB mapAorB(Source source) {
        return (source.flag) ? map(source.a) : map(source.b);
    }

    AorB map(A a); // this mapper func should be invoqued when source.flag == true
    AorB map(B b); // this mapper func should be invoqued when source.flag == false
}
```

And the MapStruct generated code will be something like:

```java
public class MapperImpl implements Mapper {
    @Override
    public Target map(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        // this is here that MapStruct call your handwritten routing function
        target.a_or_b = mapAorB( source );
        ...
    }

    // this mapper func is invoqued, not by MapStruct, but by your provided mapAorB() func when source.flag == true
    AorB map(A a) {...}

    // this mapper func is invoqued, not by MapStruct, but by your provided mapAorB() func when source.flag == false
    AorB map(B b) {...} 
}
```